# jQuery click() not getting triggered in Firefox 24

Tags: jquery, firefox, onclick, click

I'm using using jQuery to make some Ajax calls when a button is pressed.  This is working perfectly in Chrome, but clicking the button in Firefox just reloads the page.

```
<button class="form-control btn btn-primary" id="qa-next">Next</button>
// using knockout to dynamically inject values in the page.
// works when triggered manually
$('#qa-next').click(function () {
  $.post("@{QACardR}", ko.mapping.toJSON(viewModel), function(newQA) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(newQA, {}, viewModel);
  });
});
```

The

```
 $.post("@{QACardR}", ko.mapping.toJSON(viewModel), function(newQA) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(newQA, {}, viewModel);
 });
```

works correctly if I run it in the console.  But clicking the button just refreshes the page.  So I can only conclude that the problem is the selector or click not working in firefox.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `$('#qa-next').click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); $.post...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [e.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) inside your click function

```
$('#qa-next').click(function () {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.post("@{QACardR}", ko.mapping.toJSON(viewModel), function(newQA) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(newQA, {}, viewModel);
  });
});
```